# locate invalid character causing error in R xmlToDataFrame()

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, escaping

For background I am very new to R, and have almost no experience with XML files.

I wrote a webscraper using the RSelenium package that downloads XML files for multiple states and years from this [website](http://www.slforms.universalservice.org/DRT/Default.aspx), and then wrote code that reads in each file and appends it to one file and exports a CSV.  My webscraper successfully downloads all of the files I need, and the next segment of code is able to successfully read all but two of the downloaded xml files.

The first file that I am unable to read into an R dataframe can be retrieved by selecting the following options on this page: http://www.slforms.universalservice.org/DRT/Default.aspx

- Year=2013
- State=PA
- Click radio button for "XML Feed"
- Click checkbox for "select data points"
- Click checkbox for "select all data points"
- Click "build data file"

I try to read the resulting XML file into R using xmlToDataFrame:

```
install.packages("XML")
require("XML")

data_table<-xmlToDataFrame("/users/datafile.xml")
```

When I do, I get an error:

```
xmlParseCharRef: invald xmlChar value 19
Error: 1: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 19
```

The other examples I've seen of invalid character errors using xmlToDataFrame usually give two coordinates for the problematic character, but since only the value "19" is given, I'm not sure how to locate the problematic character.

Once I do find the invalid character, would there be a way to alter the text of the xml file directly to escape the invalid character, so that xmlToDataFrame will be able to read in the altered file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad encoding on this line of XML:

```
31 to $26,604.98 to remove: the ineligible entity MASTERY CHARTER SCHOOLS &#x13;
```

but the document seems to have other encoding issues as well.

The TSV works fine, so you might think abt using that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! I originally chose to download XML files because I was having troubling reading in the tsv files.  

When I try: 

`test<-read.table("N:\\My Documents\\Downloads\\Inquiry_10_8_2016_11_23_44.tsv",header=T, sep="\t")`


I get the error:

`Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 281 did not have 54 elements`